# use a subset data frame from a loop in the same loop again in R

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am trying to write this commands in a loop:

```
table1 <- table[table$ringnr == 1,] 
interaction.plot(table1$expnr, table1$disturbance, table1$flights)
table2 <- table[table$ringnr == 2,] 
interaction.plot(table2$expnr, table2$disturbance, table2$flights)
table3 <- table[table$ringnr == 3,] 
interaction.plot(table3$expnr, table3$disturbance, table3$flights)`
```

etc

This is what i have so far:

```
 for(i in 1:19){
mypath <- file.path("C:", "Users", paste("expnr_", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
jpeg(file=mypath)
assign(paste("table",i), subset(table, ringnr == i))
interaction.plot(table[i]$expnr, table[i]$disturbance, table[i]$flights)
dev.off()}
```

The first part is working and i get the data set table1, table2 etc
However, if i want to work with them in the next line R doesn't understand that i want those data set.

I know it is bad practice to use an loop for this. But does anyone know how i can work further with those dataframe created in the loop?
or can i do that with a apply function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need the table1, table2 later or only in the loop?

Comment: You assign your table to `paste("table", i)`. The assigned object is `table i`, NOT the vector you try to call in the next line (table[i])

Comment: Thanks. erocoar. i assumed it is not the vector but R did not recognize table i. 
Linus answer is exactlly what i was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need the filtered tables later, you can do this:

```
for(i in 1:19){
  mypath <- file.path("C:", "Users", paste("expnr_", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
  jpeg(file=mypath)
  temp_table <- subset(table, ringnr == i)
  interaction.plot(temp_table$expnr, temp_table$disturbance, temp_table$flights)
  dev.off()
}
```

If you need them later you can store them a list:

```
table_list<- list()
for(i in 1:19){
  mypath <- file.path("C:", "Users", paste("expnr_", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
  jpeg(file=mypath)
  table_list[[i]] <- subset(table, ringnr == i)
  interaction.plot(table_list[[i]]$expnr, table_list[[i]]$disturbance, table_list[[i]]$flights)
  dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your object `table`, `table` is a commonly used R function and you're overwriting it, you'll run into trouble at some point.

Also and more importantly here, don't create 3 tables here, put them in a list, they are numbered objects of the same kind, they should stay linked. Avoiding using `assign`at all is a good rule of thumb.

```
your_tables <- lapply(1:3,function(i) subset(your_table,ringnr == i))
```

Then you can do for example:

```
lapply(your_tables,function(x) interaction.plot(x$expnr, x$disturbance, x$flights))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I suspected that it would be possible with a apply function as well. good to know how it would work!